# Flex 4.6 TabbedViewNavigator - Fixed button width and horizontalScroll on

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, tabbar

I have a TabbedViewNavigator which has a high number of views (and therefore, also tabs). I don't want the tabs to shrink. Instead, I would like that a horizontal Scroll bar appears and some kind of indication that there is more content to the right or left.

How can I achieve that?!
[image]